# Heatmap with double annotation

Tags: python, r, annotations, heatmap

I'm trying to create a heatmap with a double annotation in the same annotation row, some more or less like this (it's a hand made example with Power Point):

[image]

Would anyone get any idea? I don't matter if the code is in R or python language.

Comment: Just add additional line (third) to specify wanted group. Not that fancy, but straightforward solution

Comment: @PoGibas, the goal is to avoid add extra lines that "mess" the image... thanks anyway for the suggestion!